# to join 5 tables how many minimum no of join's are required?

Tags: sql, oracle

how many minimum join's need for 5 table. Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: If you have 2 tables, how many joins do you need?

Comment: In case of CROSS JOIN -> 0

Comment: @jarlh  only one

Comment: @dineshdanny Hm. So...

Comment: so 4 joints need but http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/12690  in this site they had confused me. please refer

Comment: There's no limit. There could be any number of self joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four are needed.

It is as simple as laying five balls out in a straight line and counting the gaps between them.

Unless you are willing to put all of your data into one great big mess of a table, in which case you could use a CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

4 joins.

Think of it as fence panels and fenceposts. The tables are fenceposts. If you have 5 fenceposts, You will need 4 panels to fill the gaps.

```
|-|-|-|-|

table -> table -> table -> table -> table
```