# Oracle SQL: How to convert multiple (+) WHERE clauses to LEFT JOINS?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I'm trying to convert some Oracle SQL code to regular SQL and am having trouble with the numerous variables in the SELECT statement, tables in the FROM statement, and (+) WHERE statements.

I have looked through [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430274/oracle-what-does-do-in-a-where-clause) but all provide simple examples with just 2 variables, 2 tables, and 1 (+) WHERE statement. I'm not sure how to apply what I'm seeing from the other forum posts to multiple variables, tables, and (+) WHERE statements.

```
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    c.var1,
    d.var2
FROM a, b, c, d, x, y
WHERE a.ID(+) = b.ID
    AND c.var1(+) = b.var1
    AND x.id(+) = y.id;
```

I tried to convert all the (+) WHERE statements to LEFT JOINs as shown below. I did 3 LEFT JOINS, one for each (+) WHERE statement:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    c.var1,
    d.var2
FROM a, b, c, d, x, y
WHERE b.ID in 
    (SELECT b.ID
    FROM b
    LEFT JOIN a
    ON a.ID = b.ID)
```

Comment: FROM a, b, c, d, x, y. I guess, you should have 5 JOINS, but you provide much less.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256158/to-join-5-tables-how-many-minimum-no-of-joins-are-required

Comment: One query. In your case I guess it could look like FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID=b.ID LEFT JOIN c ON b.var1=c.var1  ... But x and y are not related to a,b,c and it looks suspicious

Comment: @Sergey is correct, there are 5 joins, three `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and two `CROSS JOIN`s

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query:

```sql
SELECT a.ID,
       c.var1,
       d.var2
FROM   a, b, c, d, x, y
```

can be rewritten using ANSI-join syntax as:

```sql
SELECT a.ID,
       c.var1,
       d.var2
FROM   a
       CROSS JOIN b
       CROSS JOIN c
       CROSS JOIN d
       CROSS JOIN x
       CROSS JOIN y
```

If you add in the `WHERE` clause then `WHERE c.var1(+) = b.var1` converts the `CROSS JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from `b` to `c`. Similarly for the other join conditions.

Which gives you:

```sql
SELECT a.ID,
       c.var1,
       d.var2
FROM   b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.ID = b.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.var1 = b.var1
       CROSS JOIN d
       CROSS JOIN y
       LEFT OUTER JOIN x ON x.id = y.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-tHdSD95)